# Cheap voltmeter / ammeter installed to vehicle - common ground?

Tags: current-measurement, 12v

I have a cheap Chinese voltmeter / ammeter like the one shown below.

I plan to install various 12V devices installed into my van, such as a 12V audio amp, LED strips, USB chargers, buck converters for other things like an Amazon Echo, etc. Each load will have its own 10A switch and I would also like to measure the aggregate current and incoming voltage from battery, on a master panel I plan to build.

My understanding is that it is a very good idea to common the grounds of these devices to the vehicle chassis, which is also commoned to the 12V battery's ground (and also commoned to a mains inverter's ground, and a battery-to-battery charger's ground).

Am I correct in saying I therefore cannot measure current using this little device, as the load and supply can not have a common ground?

I understand the answer should be "yes" because ammeters require connection in series, and by commoning the ground we make a parallel connection.

An secondary question is this: would it be safe to NOT tie the grounds of these devices to the chassis / vehicle ground? What would be the dangers?

However I wanted to check here if there is a good and safe solution.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you give a link to the installation instructions - hard to make any suggestions without that information.

Comment: Hello @PeterBennett, I have updated the original question with this info. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @jsotola I agree. I have edited the question to ask about the safety of not tying the loads' grounds to the vehicle chassis, which I feel is a general question more suitable to this forum.

Answer (score 2):

This meter requires current sensing on the ground side,so all accessories must be isolated from chassis ground to use this and only the meter heavy BLK wire is the common ground to chassis while it's RED goes to your new isolated common accessory ground point.

Since you are likely using > 10A , you must choose a suitable shunt to reduce the voltage drop and scale the results.

This may be inconvenient, which is why car ammeters are usually measured on the high side due to the distributed chassis grounds.

It cannot operate from a battery >30V so the bottom two diagrams show how that can be powered from a low power source.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a RV you are building.

1. "I would also like to measure the aggregate current":
   Ground is a "return path" of the current. Let the source (12V side) pass the ammeter, and then split to any loads.
2. " it is a very good idea to common the grounds of these devices to the vehicle chassis":
   No! You can likely run into more trouble than having a clean/clear dedicated main power wiring in a harness, coming through a unified power distribution panel. The reason is that not all devices are designed to directly be grounded to chassis or powered through chassis.

The main problem arises from high power devices sharing the common current (ground) path with low power devices. Aside low power/sensitive devices suffering noise generated from high power devices, it can cause vehicle fire. An example from my experiences will explain better:

Once I was called into a meeting to investigate a police car fire. The police officer was blaming the company's OBD device for the fire.
Long story short,The police was right. The company's device indeed started the fire, I had to explain, after looking at their design. What happened is that, due to the "code", the company's device was grounded to the chassis, and it was incorrect.

How that can be the problem? Unfortunately, the officer's vehicle "chassis" did not have solid continuity between the battery terminal to the high power devices. But, the company's OBD device did have good connection to battery and to chassis at the same time. So, all the return current found nice path through the company's OBD device connection.
You can see extra ground wire on the battery (-) terminal. That goes to your ECU & OBD.

Don't rely on chassis ground, don't abuse chassis ground! This applies the same to other structure/systems with ground.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. It's not an RV - just a small van we are going to use to travel around the UK from time to time. I would like music and light, and a way to get some work done on the laptop with a mobile wifi device. I have an inverter installed for a 240V fridge and mains points for general use (e.g. laptop power supply). Existing primary battery is grounded to chassis. I *do* have an isolated battery to battery charger, however I have grounded both input and output to chassis (defeating the object). Should I remove the output connection to chassis as well?

Comment: My lighting options are a bit more complicated: individually addressable 5V LED strips, which uses a wifi controller, etc... just for fun. This needs its own 12V to 5V 100W buck converter which I have also purchased. (large thing with big heatsink) I understand from what you are saying, it's best not to have any of the 12V stuff connected to chassis. What about the inverter input and output? I thought this needed to be grounded to the same ground as primary battery, which is also connected to chassis. Thanks!

Comment: Finally, when you say "the chassis did not have solid continuity between the battery terminal to the high power devices", what are you referring to with "high power devices"? You mean 120 / 240V mains devices, on an inverter? Surely the solution is to ensure good continuity? Sorry if I am misunderstanding this

Comment: @hazymat, For a multiple power source system, safety (240V) and EMI would be the concern. Here is what I would do, Hope I can explain it with my short English. Design (capacity aspects and may be other things) and draw separate wiring diagram of each power-system (a group of devices for a power source). And then, connect the ground of 'a' power-system to chassis from a single point to a single point of somewhere on the chassis.

Comment: Do that for each power-system. Do that on the paper first and try to find any possible "loop" across power-systems. ex. laptop connected to #1 power-system, that is HDMI-connected to the TV on #2 power-system. If EMI becomes problem, connect the problem device ground on chassis using a capacitor (may try 0.1uF or so).

Comment: @hazymat, High-power devices are any of relatively high power consuming devices depending on where the reference is. For the police car case, it was the vehicle's starter, alternator, headlight and etc. all could draw enough current and return to the thin ground of the OBD device. That is an example only, to help understanding of the "ground loop". How to visualize it is the key, and the approach is explained up there, "For a multiple..."